# Why do .NET console programs not deadlock the way UI programs do?

Tags: .net, asynchronous

UI programs (WPF or Windows Forms) and ASP.NET programs should use `async` and `await` thoroughly to avoid deadlock. Why does a console program not have the same requirement? For example in the following blocking on `await` in MyGetAsync and also blocking at `.Result` in MyInvoker does not cause a deadlock.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("test...");
    MyInvoker();
    Console.WriteLine("END. Press the Enter key to exit the program.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
internal static void MyInvoker()
{
    Task<string> task = MyGetAsync();
    string s = task.Result;
    if (s.Contains("doctype") || s.Contains("DOCTYPE"))
        Console.WriteLine("received an HTML page");
    else
        throw new Exception(s);
}
internal static async Task<string> MyGetAsync()
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        string response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://google.com");
        return response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to the [classic deadlock](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html):

1. Blocking on asynchronous code (that does not use `ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere).
2. An asynchronous context that only permits one thread in at a time.

Your example code always does (1) in both environments. The difference is in (2). Specifically, UI apps have a `SynchronizationContext` for their UI thread so that [`await` will naturally return to the UI thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) after the `await` completes. Console apps do not have that context, so the deadlock does not happen.

Comment: "Context" is vague. "Thread" seems to be easier to envision as a flow of control. In the example code, the flow of control is yielded in the "invoked" at await. The "invoker" soon thereafter  blocks the flow of control. When the "invoked" eventually continues, it appears it has no thread to continue because the "invoker" has blocked the thread.

Comment: @H2ONaCl: "context" is detailed in the linked blog posts. It is `SynchronizationContext.Current`, unless it is `null`, in which case it is `TaskScheduler.Current`.

Comment: Also: don't jump to thinking of threads when in the `async` world; it can be misleading. In the UI case, yes, the `SynchronizationContext` is tied to a specific UI thread. However, this exact same deadlock can occur on ASP.NET pre-Core, where the `SynchronizationContext` is *not* tied to a specific thread, but still only allows one thread *at a time*.

Comment: It doesn't have a certain context is not much different from saying it doesn't have a deadlock problem which is something already evident. I could argue "if not WPF then use magic to work despite apparent blocked method waiting on blocked method".

Comment: At the first link the section "what causes deadlock" seems to be a longer description of an apparent reason to think a deadlock is feasible. Just a longer description of what I have described here. The mystery is why the appearance is deceiving in the case of console apps.

Comment: Your second link tries to elaborate on "what is that context?". My take away from that is "if synchronization context equals null then don't deadlock". This is not an improvement on "if not WPF then don't deadlock".

Comment: "The mystery is why the appearance is deceiving in the case of console apps." - that's explained in both the link and my answer: the one-thread-at-a-time context plays a critical part of the deadlock, so when it is gone, there is no deadlock. The context is *one thread at a time*, so you can think of it as a kind of lock (it's not a lock, but for this question you can think of it as kind of acting like a lock). So "It doesn't have a certain context" *is* a viable answer; it's like saying the deadlock doesn't happen because the lock (context) that was causing the deadlock was removed.

Answer (score 1):

You interact differently with a UI such as Windows Forms and WPF, versus a console app. You generally wait until a console app tells you to do something, before you do, then you wait until it's done. As a result, there's no need to worry about thread logic contending with UI resources. With Windows Forms and WPF (any GUI really) you have a lot going on that you may not know about, and people have a hard time remembering to keep business logic out of the UI thread, or it really wouldn't be much of a problem. Now, many times, people do that when they've already written a huge chunk of their program before it finally locks up, and at that point, they have to revisit quite a lot in order to thread it out correctly..